# Javascript - Nested JSON into Array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, web

i have a little problem, i am a beginner in programming. I want to work with the Erast API, a Formula 1 API. I want to get all the drivers who won single races, the request is the following:
http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/results/1.json

Structure of the return values:

Problem is, that i dont know how to parse the JSON into a JS Array, I thought something like that:

```
var names = [];
    var index = 0;
    $.getJSON("http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/results/1.json", function(data, status) {
        $.each(data.MRData.RaceTable.Races, function(name, value) {
            //names.push(value.Results[0].Driver.givenName + " " + value.Results[0].Driver.familyName));
            obj = $.parseJSON(value);
            names.push(obj.Results[0].Driver.givenName);
            //console.log(value.Results[0].Driver.givenName+ " " + value.Results[0].Driver.familyName);
        });
    });
```

If anyone knows the answer, would appreciate hearing from you

Comment: use `$.parseJSON` on the whole JSON string and then iterate through the results.  You're trying to access `data.MRData` before you've parsed the string.

Comment: @DanielBeck, that is wrong information: jQuery does the parsing.

Comment: And without seeing sample JSON, it's difficult to know if the extra `parseJSON()` call in the loop is necessary.

Comment: Ah, whoops, I missed that it was `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get()`.  Thanks @trincot.   In that case you may not need to use parseJSON inside the loop at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to parse JSON in the loop: jQuery has already decoded the JSON when it got the response in its implementation of `$.getJSON`.

So you can do this (also using `map()`):

```js
$.getJSON("http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/results/1.json", function(data, status) {
    var names = data.MRData.RaceTable.Races.map(function(value) {
        return value.Results[0].Driver.givenName;
    });
    console.log(names);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```